# Slack - Get messages & threads for date range via Slack WebClient

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I am trying to use slack web client API to pull slack messages including threads for a specific date. The `conversations.history` API only returns the parent message in the case of threaded messages. There is `conversations.replies` API that returns the message threads, but it requires `ts` of the parent message to be passed in the request so it will only return conversations related to one thread.

Is there a way to pull all message history including replies for a data range rather than having to combine a call to `conversations.history` API and then multiple calls to `conversations.replies` for each message with thread_ts?

This approach of combining both APIs won't work if the reply was posted on the specific date we want to pull, but the root thread message was posted on an older date. The root message won't be returned in `conversations.history` and hence we won't be able to get that particular message in the thread using `conversations.replies`.

It's strange that Slack doesn't provide such API to pull all messages including threaded ones.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to capture all threads in a workspace with a single API call. The `conversations.history` is already a very data-heavy method. Most developers calling this method don't need thread information and including that in the reply would be a bit of an overkill. Calling `conversations.replies` should return all the replies corresponding to that parent message regardless of the date it was posted in unless otherwise specified using the `latest` or `oldest` parameters.